# How to set a variable from one class equals to a variable in another class in Django models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a new in Django world and I want to link two classes from models.py so that i can set their variables equal to each other. Here is the models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your models here.


class file(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    FILE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('audio','Audio'),
        ('games','Games'),
        ('videos','Videos'),
        ('applications','Applications'),
        ('books','Books/Docs'),
        ('others','Others')
        )
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=FILE_TYPE_CHOICES,default='others')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=6000)
    #uploader_username = ???

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('one:user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class user (models.Model):
    username= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.EmailField
    password= models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user_files = models.ForeignKey(file, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here I want to set `uploader_username` from `file` class equals to`username` from `user` class.

Comment: `uploader_username = user.username` ?

Comment: You would want to basically have association between User and File models. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to do this. You want a ForeignKey from File to User, not the other way round, then you can just access `my_file.user.username`.

Note, it is a bad idea to define your own user class like this. There can be good reasons for doing so, but if so you must inherit from the abstract base classes in the auth app; failure to do so is a serious security problem as you will be storing passwords in clear text. It doesn't look like you need your own model here; you should remove this class.